# How to find all cases of x or less number of neighboring polygons that can be merged to form a bigger polygon of a minimum given area?

Tags: arcmap

I have 1500 land parcels where I need to identify all such instances where 10 or less number of neighboring plots can be merged to form a bigger plot of minimum 2000 sqm area. First, I need to identify all such instances and then in the next step, merge those said plots to form the bigger plots. (I'm using ArcMap for the analysis, by the way.)

Comment: This is a complex issue. Search the internet for "Zonal Design GIS".